# Function for formatting a partition or returning a partition type

Tags: c++, partition, disk-partitioning

Is there an API function for formatting a partition ? Or for returning the partition type of an already formatted partition ?

I want to be able to programatically format the single partition of a thumb drive. If the thumb drive is already formatted I want to reformat the partition with the partition type which already exists on it, otherwise I want to format it for the first time with a user-supplied partition type. The language is C/C++, and as most Unix/Linux APIs are for C I should have no problems with the API if I can figure out what it is.

This is a programming question so answers like use xxx command is not what I am looking for. Any help in the direction I need to go will be appreciated.

Comment: libfdisk, see https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/libfdisk/samples/mkpart.c

Comment: Too obscure. care to tell me more ?